# « C'est … que » ou « c'était … que » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, emphase

J'aimerais bien savoir quelle phrase est utilisée par les francophones.

> C'est cette fille que j'adorais.

ou

> C'était cette fille que j'adorais.

Dans des cas semblables, est-ce que je dois conjuguer le verbe *être* au présent ou à l'imparfait ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La subordonnée relative *que j'adorais* n'a pas d'influence sur le temps à utiliser pour *être* ; suivant le contexte et le sens désiré, on va utiliser le présent, l'imparfait ou un autre temps.

Exemples (tirés des commentaires).

> Tiens, regarde cette vieille photo! C'**est** cette fille que j'adorais.
>
> Je lui ai montré une vieille photo. C'**était** cette fille que j'adorais.
>
> Rendez-vous demain à l'arrivée du train. Je ne pourrai pas venir, mais j'enverrai quelqu'un te chercher. Ce **sera** cette fille que j'adorais et qui était venue avec moi à Bruxelles, je crois qu'il n'y a qu'elle qui te connait.

Comment: Un exemple pour tenter d'illustrer la différence: "Tiens, regarde cette vieille photo! C'est cette fille que j'adorais." (on montre dans le présent la fille adorée dans le passé), à comparer avec "Je lui ai montré une vieille photo. C'était cette fille que j'adorais." (on a montré dans le passé la fille adorée).

Comment: Mais je ne vois pas dans quel contexte on pourrait dire _Ce sera cette fille que j'adorais_ ?... Si vous confirmez, il n'y aurait donc pas totale indépendance ?

Comment: (+1) N'y aurait-il pas, dans la formulation *C'est cette fille que j'adorais*, l'aveu en demi-teinte d'un amour continué? *Ce sera cette fille que j'adorais* n'est rien moins que de la poésie.

Comment: @Istao,« Rendez-vous demain à l'arrivée du train. Je ne pourrai pas venir, mais j'enverrai quelqu'un te chercher. Ce sera cette fille que j'adorais et qui étais venue avec moi à Bruxelles, je crois qu'il n'y a qu'elle qui te connait. »

Comment: AH oui je vois, merci :-)

Comment: Merci de votre suivi

Answer (score -1):

C'était cette fille que j'adorais.

L'autre est correcte mais, dans un parler très relaché.

Comment: Véridique. On ne change pas le temps de la phrase, c'est incorrect. Même si cela tends à se démocratiser.